# Exploding Kittens Nope Cards

Tags: exploding-kittens

Who can play a nope card?  Scenario: Player A plays an attack.  Can player C put down a nope card to block the attack on player B?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Anyone can play a Nope card at any time (except for an Exploding Kitten or Defuse Card), from [the rules](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/exploding-kittens):

> Stop any action except for an Exploding Kitten or a Defuse Card. Imagine that any card beneath a Nope Card never existed.
>
> You can also play a Nope on another Nope to negate it and create a Yup, and so on.
>
> You can play a Nope Card **at any time before an action has begun, even if it’s not your turn**. Any cards that have been noped are lost. Leave them in the Discard Pile. You can even play a Nope on a SPECIAL COMBO

So yes, if player C wants to block an attack from player A on player B, they can.

See also how the attack rules explicitly use victim and someone:

> (If the **victim** of an ATTACK CARD also plays an ATTACK CARD, their turns are immediately over, and the next player must take two turns.)
>
> If you play an ATTACK CARD and **someone** plays a NOPE on top of it, this means that you still have to draw a card and the next player does NOT have to take two turns.